# Handling Barcode Scanner Input From Zebra Device (TC51/56)

Tags: javascript, cordova, sapui5, barcode-scanner

I have a Cordova app which will be using the Zebra TC51/56 device for input. The device has a hard button on each side which activates the barcode scanning laser.

The issue I'm having is that if I monitor for a keyup or keydown event the whole barcode doesn't get placed into the input box where I want it....only the 1st character.

I've noticed that if I use the Chrome debugger and put a breakpoint in the event listener so that is stops then I get the whole barcode. I'm using SAP UI5/Fiori components as well if that makes any difference.

Has anyone dealt with input from the Zebra devices before?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use Intent output rather than keyboard output as the device outputs key events rather than key presses so some devices will not register them properly in the browser.

There is a tutorial on using Intents with Cordova at https://developer.zebra.com/community/android/android-forums/android-blogs/blog/2016/08/04/integrating-datawedge-into-your-cordova-application

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't listen for an input or change event instead of keyup / keydown? Javascript is going to take the ball and run with it unless you tie the event listener to the change of the input field.

Comment: Switching to just looking for the 'input' event did the trick.